# I can't upgrade Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: system-installation

I received my copy from a friend, and when I try to upgrade, it keeps saying there is a problem with my Internet connection, but I can access everything online.

Also I can not install anything so please help thank you.

I don't know much about Ubuntu, I just like how stable it is.

Answer (score -3):

Hmm, first try this : 
Go to Applications > Accessories > Terminal

Now write the next :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And hit enter, after finish write this and hit enter :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then write and hit enter :

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That should work,maybe you will be asked to type y or press enter later

If that doesn't work go to the update manager and click settings, from then find the " Download from : ***_*___** and see if the place typed in the blank space is nearest to you, if it is not then change it and try again, hope it helps :D

[Or try this](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)

Comment: This won't work on an unsupported release.

Comment: maybe this will solve it then : https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html